# Borrar pantalla en Mac. Lenguaje C

Tags: c, funciones, macos

Me preguntaba si la función `system(“clear”);` funciona en Mac
o, caso contrario ¿hay otra diferente para este sistema operativo? 
Ya que solamente tengo Linux para probar!
Gracias!

Comment: Hola Alexa, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla). Esta pregunta no se ajusta bien al formato del sitio (Stack Overflow no es un sustituto de Google o una búsqueda online) y sería casi más apropiada para el chat (aunque comprendo que aún no tienes puntos suficientes para entrar ahí). Lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) para más información.

Answer (score 2):

Al margen de que, como explica eferion, no hay forma estándar de borrar la pantalla desde C, lo que sí existe es un estándar de códigos de escape (ANSI X3.64) al que muchas terminales se ciñen, y que permitiría borrarla de forma sencilla desde cualquier lenguaje de programación.

Siguiendo este estándar, si la terminal recibe ciertas secuencias de caracteres, realizará ciertas acciones. En concreto, si recibe la secuencia de códigos (los escribo en hexadecimal) `1b`, `5b`, `32`, `4a`, borrará la pantalla.

Estos códigos representan respectivamente, el código ASCII del "escape", el código ascii del símbolo `[`, el código ASCII del dígito `2` y el código ascii de la letra `J`.

Desde un programa en C puedes enviar esa secuencia de códigos a la salida estándar mediante:

```
printf("\033[2J");
```

El `\033` es una forma de introducir en una cadena cualquier código ASCII no imprimible, escribiéndolo en octal (base 8). En esa base 33 equivale al `1b` hexadecimal.

Si la salida estándar de ese programa está conectada a una terminal compatible con el estándar ANSI antes mencionado, se borrará la pantalla. Tienes más posibles códigos de escape [en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI)

### ¿Qué terminales son compatibles?

- La consola de linux
- Los emuladores de terminales de linux (xterm, y los demás)
- La aplicación `Terminal` de OSX (mac)
- Otros muchos emuladores de terminal para OSX, como `iterm`
- Aplicaciones para acceso remoto vía ssh (como `putty` para windows, y las aplicaciones de conexión remota para Android como JuiceSSH o Termius para iOS, entre otras muchas)

No es compatible:

- La terminal de windows (`cmd.exe`)

  Aunque [parece ser](https://superuser.com/a/1050078) que desde la actualización Windows 10 Anniversary Update si que lo soporta, pero no por defecto, debe ser habilitado y no tengo claro cómo.

En resumen, me atrevería a decir que el truco *funcionaría básicamente en todas partes menos en Windows*.

Y desde luego, para Linux es una alternativa más eficiente que `system("clear")`, ya que lo que hace `system()` es crear un nuevo proceso (`fork()`), cargar dentro de él un intérprete de comandos (`bash` o el que uses por defecto), y pedirle que ejecute `"clear"`. Y para ello, el intérprete de comandos recién cargado tendrá que buscar en el `PATH` un ejecutable llamado `clear`, y cargarlo en memoria, para lo que  necesita hacer otro proceso (`fork()`) dentro del cual carga el ejecutable `clear`, y espera a que éste finalice, tras lo cual el shell a su vez finaliza y `system()` retorna.  Como ves, muchos pasos, y todo para que al final, muy probablemente, el comando `clear` se limite a enviar a la terminal `"\033[2J"`.

Comment: Estaría bien que el estándar incluyese por fin una función para limpiar la pantalla... así no tendríamos que inyectar secuencias así en nuestro código

Answer (score 1):

En C no hay ninguna forma estándar de borrar la pantalla.

El ejemplo que propones, es decir, usar `system("clear")` únicamente podría funcionar en aquellos sistemas que tengan una aplicación llamada `clear` cuyo cometido sea limpiar la consola.

Pero, como te digo, el estándar de C no contempla ningún mecanismo que permita realizar esta tarea, luego para limpiar la pantalla solo te queda recurrir a funciones propias del sistema operativo en el que estás trabajando, lo que resulta en una solución no portable, o recurrir a librerías de terceros (a ser posible multiplataforma) que incorporen esta funcionalidad... en este caso tu aplicación estará ligada a esta librería y eso no siempre es una opción (por ejemplo en los deberes de clase).

En este caso concreto no hay una respuesta buena, lo siento.